# What is the best way to create a large ZIP file with Rails data and send it to Amazon S3 storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a feature in a Ruby on Rails application that backs up all of a user's account data so they can download it in a ZIP file and store it locally.

To create the ZIP file, I'm doing the following:

1. Using ZIP::OutputStream to open a ZIP file stream.
2. Going through each of the relevant models in the users account, converting all the records in that model to a CSV, then adding each CSV to the ZIP file.
3. Sending the resulting ZIP file to AWS S3.

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate the process:

```
output_stream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zos| 

    @models_to_backup.each do |model|
       csv = model.convert_to_csv_file
       zos.put_next_entry("csv_files/#{model.name}.csv")
       zos.write csv
    end

end

output_stream.rewind
SendFileToS3(output_stream)
```

This works fine for smaller files, but most users have upwards of 100,000 records.  Thus, as the ZIP::OutputStream is generating, I quickly run into memory issues (I'm hosting the app on Heroku) because the output stream is all being stored in memory until it's sent.

Is there a more memory efficient way to create these ZIP files?  Is there a way to stream the ZIP to S3 in batches as it's created, to avoid creating the entire ZIP file in memory?  Or, will I just need to provision a higher memory-limit server to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it possible that the memory issue is due to `@models_to_backup` and not due to `zos`?

Comment: I've done a pretty good job (as far as I'm aware) of optimizing the query for @models_to_backup , so I'm not sure I can completely solve the problem just be changing that method.  Appreciate the help though!

Comment: What do you estimate is the maximum number of records that might be included in `@models_to_backup`? Is that your "upwards of 100,000" number? Or some other number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone sees this in the future.  After looking into this for several days, I couldn't find a great solution.

My somewhat hacky workaround is to just temporarily use a Heroku Performance-L dyno (which has 14GB of memory) when I'm running the backups (only has to happen once a month.)  Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.